# Finding occurrences of overlapping date ranges in two tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date

I would like to check if any of given date ranges in collection overlaps with ranges retrieved from db. Hopefully I'd like to perform it in one query.

As explained in PostgreSQL docs, `OVERLAPS` method is used like this:

```
SELECT ('2001-02-16', '2001-12-21') OVERLAPS
       ('2001-10-30', '2002-10-30');
Result: true
```

Is there any possibility of providing `OVERLAPS` with a collection of date ranges? Something like:

```
SELECT ('2001-02-16', '2001-12-31'), ('2002-01-01', 2002-12-31), (...) OVERLAPS
       ('2001-10-30', '2002-10-30'), (...);
Result: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have some partial answer. Let's say I have table `t1`:

```
 starts_at  |  ends_at   
------------+------------
 2001-01-01 | 2001-01-02
 2001-01-05 | 2001-01-06
 2001-01-08 | 2001-01-09
```

I would like to check if there are any occurrences of overlapping dates between `t1` and some given date ranges. So far I have managed to solve it without `overlaps`:

```
WITH t2(starts_at, ends_at) AS(
  VALUES('2001-01-01'::DATE, '2001-01-05'::DATE),
        ('2001-01-12'::DATE, '2001-01-15'::DATE))
SELECT * 
FROM t1, t2
WHERE 
   t1.starts_at < t2.ends_at AND t1.ends_at >= t2.starts_at;
```

And the result is somehow satisfying, as it gives me:

```
 starts_at  |  ends_at   | starts_at  |  ends_at   
------------+------------+------------+------------
 2001-01-01 | 2001-01-02 | 2001-01-01 | 2001-01-05
(1 row)
```

Then I'd like to throw an exception in my app if there is any row present. Is this a correct way to do it?

Comment: `OVERLAPS` like many postgres functions is sort of a *shortcut* to a larger expression, so it is fine to replace it with something else. Your query looks just fine +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to collect all intervals you want and after that fire the `OVERLAPS` function with this data to a given interval, e.g.

```
WITH j(start_date,end_date) AS ( 
  VALUES ('2001-02-16'::DATE, '2001-12-21'::DATE),
         ('2002-01-01'::DATE, '2002-12-31'::DATE),
         ('2019-01-01'::DATE, '2020-01-01'::DATE))
SELECT (start_date,end_date) OVERLAPS ('2001-10-30'::DATE, '2002-10-30'::DATE)
FROM j;

 overlaps 
----------
 t
 t
 f
(3 Zeilen)
```

Comment: Is there any way to use `overlaps` on two tables? I tried putting select statement after `overlaps`, it didn't work though.

Comment: Do both tables contain start and end dates? Can you add a sample?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying enough, but yes, both tables will have start and end dates. I have provided more details in comment below.

Comment: Consider closing the question, so that other people can find it more easily.